# How to display a row from a database?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing, nullpointerexception

I've tried every method I found here on how to simply display a row of my database and nothing happens. Tried using the java.sql.Statement but for some reason it was giving me an error on the only setString I need; tried changing the Statement library but nothing happen. The last thing I've tried is what I have on the code, but it doesn't even throw me an error, it just pops up an empty JOptionPane. Any thoughs on what could be wrong?

```
JButton btnDisplayInfo = new JButton("Display Info");
        btnDisplayInfo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String petname = txtName.getText();

                Connection conn = null;
                //Statement pstmt = null;

                try {
                    String sql = "SELECT PETPHOTO, PETTYPE, COLOR, GENDER, ISSTERILIZED, PEDIGREE, DATE_ENTRY, VACCINE1, VACCINE2, VACCINE3 FROM PETS WHERE PETNAME=?";
                    PreparedStatement pr = conn.prepareStatement(sql); //Error appears to be here
                    pr.setString(1, petname);
                    ResultSet rs = pr.executeQuery();
                    while(rs.next()) {
                        String photo = rs.getString("PETPHOTO");
                        String type = rs.getString("PETTYPE");
                        String color = rs.getString("COLOR");
                        int gender = rs.getInt("GENDER");
                        int isSte = rs.getInt("ISSTERILIZED");
                        String pedigree = rs.getString("PEDIGREE");
                        String date_entry = rs.getString("DATE_ENTRY");
                        String vac1 = rs.getString("VACCINE1");
                        String vac2 = rs.getString("VACCINE2");
                        String vac3 = rs.getString("VACCINE3");

                        System.out.println(photo + type + color + gender + isSte + pedigree + date_entry + vac1 + vac2 + vac3);
                    }
                }catch(Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
        btnDisplayInfo.setBounds(42, 127, 340, 48);
        contentPane.add(btnDisplayInfo);


/**
DATABASE:
CREATE DATABASE refugio;

USE refugio;

CREATE TABLE Pets
(
   petName VARCHAR(15) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   petPhoto VARCHAR(50) NULL,
   petType VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
   color VARCHAR(15),
   gender TINYINT(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '0 - female, 1 - male',
   isSterilized TINYINT(1) COMMENT '0 - NO, 1 - YES',
   pedigree VARCHAR(15),
   date_entry timestamp NOT NULL,
   vaccine1 VARCHAR(15) NULL,
   vaccine2 VARCHAR(15) NULL,
   vaccine3 VARCHAR(15) NULL
);
*/
```

Comment: I think `txtName.getText()` is not returning a String. Try to print `petname` and see what is being returned by `txtName.getText()`

Comment: Tried printing the txtName.getText() and is working fine

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB.

Comment: BTW - change `}catch(Exception ex) { JOptionPane..` to `}catch(Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); JOptionPane..` for more (IE **useful**) output on the error.

Comment: BTW (again): `btnDisplayInfo.setBounds(42, 127, 340, 48);` Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 2) `contentPane.add(btnDisplayInfo);` Don't add components dynamically. Add the button on construction and `setEnabled(false)`. Enable it when needed.

Comment: So I added the ex.printStackTrace and now I can see an error; It says java.lang.NullPointerException on the PreparedStatement line.

Comment: See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)

Comment: BTW (3): I'd ask you to [edit] the question to add the stack trace (not a stack **tree**) but once you've read the two latest Q&A's you'll hopefully realise why the stack trace is not much use to us unless we have an MRE / SSCCE.

Comment: You are assigning your Connection to null. This is why you get a NullPointerException:   `Connection conn = null;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning your Connection to null. This is why you get a NullPointerException: `Connection conn = null;`

You need to assign the Connection using `conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);`

You need to set the connection to your database correctly.

Comment: But isn't it suppose to be on null? even here [JDBC](https://www.javaworld.com/article/3388036/what-is-jdbc-introduction-to-java-database-connectivity.html) they set the connection to null; what should it be connected to then?

Comment: Have a look at the Java tutorial: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html)

Comment: conn is initiaised to 0, but then it needs to be assigned using `conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);`

Comment: @escobarveras, *even here ... they set the connection to null;* - well look at the statement two lines down. When you follow a tutorial follow the whole code not just parts of it.